# How to implement an ever-present button in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to implement a button on an App which should be always present on all the screens of the app. That means the button will be on the top layer all the time, no matter the application switches between its views. The function of the button is to invoke a particular module at any point of time while running the main app. The button should also be capable to moved around. Please help if you have any idea on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the button as a subview to the window of the application immediately the app has lunched in

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Answer (score 1):

make your button as a subview to the window, and with this [UIView+Hierarchy category](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/uivewi-category-to-manage-z-order-of-views/) you can achieve your goal.